# Disable sync on each bookmark change

Tags: firefox, firefox-sync

Each time I add or change a bookmark in Firefox, the bookmarks functionality in unusable for a period of 5-20 seconds as Firefox resyncs. **Is there any way to disable the automatic resync?** I have added the Sync button to the toolbar which I can press whenever I would like to initiate a sync.

I have added the boolean preference `services.sync.autoconnect` with the value `false` however the problem persists. Additionally, I set `services.sync.syncInterval` and `services.sync.scheduler.immediateInterval` to `86400000` however the problem persists.

I have set Firefox Sync to sync *only* bookmarks. This is on Kubuntu 14.04 with Firefox 32.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a valid problem, and I've outlined the steps that I've taken to resolve the issue which did not help. How might I improve the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After dealing with this issue for some time, I found a work around, if not a real fix. Under `Preferences -> Sync` one can disable *all* Sync items (bookmarks, tabs, etc.) but leave the Firefox Account logged in. When no Sync items are checked, Firefox will not sync automatically.

To initiate a sync, check the items to be synced, press the sync button, and then uncheck the items again.

Or, just use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) (which comes with problems of its own).